# Shell script: bad substitution in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: bash, shell, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm writing some CI commands inside Bitbucket Pipelines and I'd like to know why the following script isn't working. I tested it locally and it works, but in CI, I have a `syntax error: bad substitution`. I tried to `echo $SHELL` to know in which type of shell it's running into but it didn't return anything.

```yaml
# For the example
- env=staging
- ENV_STAGING=aGVsbG8=
# Convert environment variable to uppercase
- ENVIRONMENT=$(echo $env | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
# Create env file name
- ENV_FILE_NAME=ENV_${ENVIRONMENT}
# Decode the env variable value and store it into a .env file
- echo ${!ENV_FILE_NAME} | base64 --decode >> .env
```

```
+ echo ${!ENV_FILE_NAME} | base64 --decode >> .env
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/shellScript49232494857234908572.sh: line 14: syntax error: bad substitution
```

Comment: @tshiono Yes there is. That's the syntax for indirect variables.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script with `bash`? Indirect variables are a bash extension, so this won't work with `sh`.

Comment: Oh, got it, I don't think it's running with `bash` indeed! How could I change the script to work with `sh` then?

Comment: `eval echo \$$ENV_FILE_NAME`?

Comment: See the linked question.

Comment: Can you answer to the post so I can mark your answer as solution ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to answer a question once it has been closed as a duplicate.